# TupleConstructor in groovy with arguments for superclass

Tags: inheritance, groovy, constructor, annotations

I have the following code pattern in my code

```
class A {
    String x
    String y
    String z
    A() { }
    A(String a) { } 
}

@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class B extends A {
   B(String x, String y) {
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.z = ""
   }
}

@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class C extends B {
    String r
}

println new B("x1", "y1").x

println new C("x2", "y2", "r").r
```

What I try to achieve is to be able to create `C` object like in the last line. What I get is an error.

```
Could not find matching constructor for: B(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Is there a way to achieve this through annotations (avoiding having to write a constructor in C myself)?
​
// You can try the code on https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid situation where constructors are implemented manually and generated with AST transformation in the same time. You shouldn't mix `@TupleConstructor` with `@InheritConstructor` as well. The latest (Groovy 2.4.12) [`TupleConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) class Javadoc is very enigmatic and it says:

> (...) Do not use with [`InheritConstructors`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/InheritConstructors.html).

and if you check `InheritConstructors` Javadoc you will see:

> (...) Do not use with [`TupleConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html).

Javadoc for Groovy **2.5.0-SNAPSHOT** says more in section "Known Limitations":

> #### Known Limitations:
>
> - This AST transform might become a no-op if you are defining your own constructors or combining with other AST transforms which create constructors (e.g. `@InheritConstructors`); the order in which the particular transforms are processed becomes important in that case. See the force attribute for further details about customizing this behavior.
> - This AST transform normally uses default parameter values which creates multiple constructors under the covers. You should use with care if you are defining your own constructors or combining with other AST transforms which create constructors (e.g. `@InheritConstructors`); the order in which the particular transforms are processed becomes important in that case. See the defaults attribute for further details about customizing this behavior.
> - Groovy's normal map-style naming conventions will not be available if the first property (or field) has type `LinkedHashMap` or if there is a single Map, AbstractMap or HashMap property (or field)
>
> *Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html*

According to those information the way you can try achieve your expected behavior is to get rid of hand-written constructors and use `@TupleConstructor` instead for all classes in the hierarchy, e.g.

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor
class A {
    String x
    String y
    String z
}

@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class B extends A {
}

@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class C extends B {
    String r
}

println new B("x1", "y1").x

println new C("x2", "y2", "r").r
```

EDIT: If modifying class `A` is not an option then you can achieve this by following class hierarchy:

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

class A {
    String x
    String y
    String z
    A() { }
    A(String a) { }
}

@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties = true)
class B extends A {
}

@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class C extends B {
    String r
}

println new C("x2", "y2", "z2", "r2").dump()
```

Running following script returns to output:

```
<C@670002 r=r2 x=x2 y=y2 z=z2>
```

What happens here is:

- Class `A` is unchanged.
- Class `B` adds constructor for all fields inherited from `A`
- Class `C` adds missing constructor that satisfies initialization of field `r`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer. You can ignore @InheritConstructors. It's not important and I can delete it. But I still get the error without it. My issue is that you can think of class A as code from a library. I'd rather not change the definition of A. I can apply changes in B and C.

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinis Thanks for explaining that. I've updated the answer to follow this requirement. Hope it helps.